# Method of Moment for Gamma Distribution

Tags: gamma-distribution, method-of-moments

I know that the empirical $r$-th moment is defined as:

$$\hat E(X^r) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n   x_i^r $$

So for the first moment I did:
$$E_{\lambda,\alpha}(X) = \hat E(X) = \bar X $$
$$\bar X =  \frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$$
$${\alpha}=\lambda \bar X$$

For the second moment:
\begin{align}E_{\alpha,\lambda}(X^2) & = \hat E[X^2] \\
& = \frac{(\alpha + 1) \alpha}{\lambda^2}\\
& = \frac{(\lambda \bar X + 1) \lambda \bar X }{\lambda^2}\\
& = \lambda \bar X^2 + \bar X = \lambda \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n   x_i^2 
\end{align}

Know, this is where I´m stuck, I know for a fact, that the end equation must be, but I´m not sure how:

$$\lambda = \frac{\bar X}{ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - \bar X^2} $$

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph or screenshot (see 
[here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question,
add the [tag:self-study] tag & read 
[its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. 
We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen How do I write math notation? And I don't get what else you want me to write, I just show you everything I did, the only thing they gave me was the equation that I had to get at the end

Comment: For writing math notation see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is way wrong from the first line. E(X) is a *parameter*, and x-bar is a *statistic*. We use statistics to estimate parameters, but clearly understanding the distinction between statistics and parameters is fundamental to statistical thinking. Get that straight before trying to go any further.

Comment: @RussLenth What do you mean? The first moment is 1/ Summation of Xi^1, that's the Mean X-Bar, so what's wrong? I'm genuinely asking

Comment: The mean of the dats is not the same as the mean of the distribution. The latter is unvarying, but the mean of the data changes when you get a different set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sequence
\begin{align}E_{\alpha,\lambda}(X^2)
& = \frac{(\alpha + 1) \alpha}{\lambda^2}\\
& = \frac{(\lambda \bar X + 1) \lambda \bar X }{\lambda^2}\tag{1}\\
& = \lambda \bar X^2 + \bar X \tag{2}\\
& = \hat E[X^2] \\
& = \lambda \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n   x_i^2 \tag{3}
\end{align}
there is a mistake in (1), which makes (2) wrong. And there is an extra $\lambda$ in (3).